# How to remove of MUI 5 TextField label without having notched style?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on replacing the DatePicker component in our app with the new @mui DatePicker, and I'm having some trouble getting the TextField to render without the floating label and the notched input style. Here is my latest attempt:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <DatePicker
    onError={(reason, value) => console.log(reason, value)}
    disableOpenPicker
    className={styles.datepicker}
    disableMaskedInput
    onChange={() => undefined}
    onAccept={handleAccept}
    open={datePickerVisible}
    value={getSafeDate(value) as Date}
    onClose={partial(handleDatepickerVisibilityChange, false)}
    {...datepickerProps}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        id={id}
        {...inputProps}
        {...params}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        error={errorText !== null}
        helperText={errorText}
        onBlur={handleValueChange}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        hiddenLabel
        size='small'
        fullWidth
      />
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I've tried many different combinations for TextField props, such as adding `InputLabelProps={{shrink:false}}`, `InputLabelProps={{shrink:true}}`, and `inputProps={{notched:false}}` but always end up looking like this: [image: wonky TextField style]

Does anyone have an idea of how to correct this, or if it's possible?
Thanks!

Comment: I created a simple example app with a datepicker and textfield but I cannot see this notch. You might have css from somewhere else affecting it. I would suggest inspecting this with browser dev tools

Comment: Yup, just found it, bootstrap is overriding the legend styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was fixed in  [release v5.4.0](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.4.0)

> ​[TextField] Remove notch when no label is added (#30560) @alisasanib

Updating to v5.4.0 should solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using the latest and still seeing this issue. I'm debugging in the browser and it's still rendering the notched outline, even with the settings above. I'm stepping through and the properties as they're being passed down are correct, but no dice. Today I've also tried explicitly setting the `notched: false` and `label: null` on the TextField `InputProps' property. Looking at the code in github it shouldn't be rendering the notched style or the label. I'm unsure why this is happening. I tried it in a codesandbox and it's not happening there :/

Comment: Okay, I found it, looks like bootstrap is being pulled into my application, and it's overriding the legend styling.